# Clone of Internet Explorer

Tags: web-browser, user-interface, internet-explorer

Microsoft is moving from Internet Explorer to Edge, and Yahoo! and other sites are dropping support for Internet Explorer.

I wonder if there's a browser that is a clone of Internet Explorer 5 but doesn't have any Internet Explorer code but has the classic Internet Explorer user interface. And a clone of Internet Explorer 10 as well that has the same basic UI. I want clones of both, clones that are supported and updated.

I don't care if it's proprietary freeware or open-source. And it's no big deal if it is only available for Windows, but it would be good if it was available for Linux and Mac. I don't care if it uses the Trident engine, Webkit or its fork Blink/V8, or Gecko or its successors Servo and Quantum, or its own engine. But I might like triple-engine kind of like Lunascape and Avant but with a different UI.

This idea is kind of analogous to Linux being a clone of Unix, not exactly. I'm just talking about browsers rather than operating systems. It's also like Pale Moon is a clone of old Firefox... sort of. Or ReactOS is a clone of Windows and FreeDOS is a clone of MS-DOS... sort of.

Is there any browser that's anything like what I'm describing above?

Comment: Are you sure in ie5? Ie6 was far more longer used. Ms won the browser war, and stopped the development on the spot. I think, the gui could be easily done by a modified firefox, but I would be surprised if anybody had done it.

Comment: Oops! I miscommunicated. I want a clones of both of them, clones that are supported.

Comment: The look and feel of IE is probably copyrighted or trademarked, I doubt you could legally do that except on your home PC.

Comment: Am I the only one that likes the look and feel of Internet Explorer better than Chrome and Edge? I like it much better.

Comment: If Microsoft did away with the look and feel, why didn't Microsoft just give the rights to it away?